# Create multiple csv extracts by subsetting data frame

Tags: r, loops, subset, export-to-csv

I have searched numerous Q&As but not found a solution yet for this problem... (see attempts below)

I have a transactional dataset `MAC_trans_sales_members` where each transaction is assigned to a customer ID, and each customer assigned to a cohort e.g. '01/2016' in the `join.cohort`column. There are 4M customers so too many rows for 1 excel file, so I would like to create separate subsets for each join cohort, and export each subset to a separate csv. There are around 18 cohorts, so I want to automate this subsetting.

I have tried the following bits of code, but none of them work:

attempt 1

```
dt <- MAC_trans_sales_members
setDT(dt)[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", join.cohort,".csv")), 
      by = join.cohort, .SDcols=names(dt) ]

Error: is.character(file) && length(file) == 1 && !is.na(file) is not TRUE
```

attempt 2

```
setDT(MAC_trans_sales_members)[, write.csv(.SD, paste0("output_", join.cohort,".csv")), 
by = join.cohort, .SDcols=names(MAC_trans_sales_members) ]

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

attempt 3

```
daply(MAC_trans_sales_members, .(join.cohort), write.csv)
```

...just spews out lines of data in the console

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

`join.cohort` is a vector in `j` in your code. use `unique`

```
MAC_trans_sales_members[, 
    fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", unique(join.cohort), ".csv")),
    by=join.cohort]
```

for your attempt 3, the `file` argument to `write.csv` is not passed in.

Comment: Thanks - have made your change by adding `unique`, but now I'm still getting error messages:


  `Error in fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", unique(join.cohort), ".csv")) : 
  No such file or directory: 'output_02/2016.csv'. Unable to create new file for writing (it does not exist already). Do you have permission to write here, is there space on the disk and does the path exist?`

any thoughts?

Comment: The file path output_02/2016.csv must exist for it to work. Check if the folder output_02 is in your working directory which you can check using 'getwd()'

Comment: Thanks - the variables in `join.cohort` are in the format 01/2016, 02/2016 etc., so the output code was taking the "/" as a folder level. I rewrote the "/" to "-" and now it exports fine, and so quickly!